# In unity C# how do I make the moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); not read the arrow keys and only detect a and d on the keyboard

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok so I am making a metroidvania and I am using some simple inputs in the code but I want to use the arrow keys for special abilities and the wasd keys for movement. When I use my code it reads wasd and arrow keys. How do I make it only detect wasd and not detect arrow keys? Please help! Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControler : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed;
public float jumpforce;
private float moveInput;

private Rigidbody2D rb;

private bool facingRight = true;

private bool isGrounded;
public Transform GroundCheck;
public float checkRadius;
public LayerMask whatIsground;

private int extraJumps;
public int extraJumpsValue;

void Start()
{
    extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{


    moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);

    if(facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }else if(facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
}

void Update()
{
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsground);

    if (isGrounded == true)
    {
        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && extraJumps > 0)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpforce;
        extraJumps--;
    }else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && extraJumps == 0 && isGrounded == true)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpforce;
    }
}

void Flip()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
    Scaler.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = Scaler;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

It depends what input system you're using. Assuming you're using the old system, go to Edit > Project Settings > Input. Find the "Horizontal" axis and change whatever keys or alt keys you want.

Comment: No problem, but FYI you're not supposed to comment thanking people because comments are for hashing out the issue or getting clarification. Upvoting answers and marking an answer as best answer is a big thing on stack overflow. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers